# what is the equivalent of __setitem__ in c#

Tags: c#, deserialization

I am using a class to deserialize some bytes.
In python, **setitem** is used as below:

```
## python code
class xdict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            selfval = self[key] # the value already there
            if type(selfval) == list:
                selfval.append(value)
            else:
                super(xdict, self).__setitem__(key, [selfval] + [value])
        else:
            if type(value) == xdict: # convert nested BSON documents (xdicts) to a dictionary
                super(xdict, self).__setitem__(key, value.to_dict())
            else:
                super(xdict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

and now I'm trying to do that in c#.
I tried something like:

```
// c# code:
class XDict
{
    private Hashtable table = new Hashtable();

    public XDict(string key, object value)
    {
    // stuff...
    }
}
```

but I get an error "...does not match any field or property of class Test.common.XDict"

Comment: Have you looked into a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You have not shown the code generating the error, nor given the actual error text, both are very important in diagnosing the problem.  You also shouldn't use `HashTable` at all, it's pretty much entirely obsolete at this point; you should use `Dictionary` instead.

Answer (score 2):

A more simple way to do it that Ben's version is just to extend the dictionary class itself, instead of having a dictionary field in a new class.

```
public class XDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public new TValue this[TKey key] 
    {
        get { return base[key]; }   // get item calling the base implementation
        set 
        { 
               if(value.Equals(default(TValue))) // additional logic (OPTIONAL)
                   return;                       // Don't add default values
               base[key] = value; // set item calling the base implementation 
        }  
    }
}
```

And you would use it like:

```
{
    XDictionary<string, object> xDict = new XDictionary<string,object>();
    xDict["Test"] = 5; // This will call the set { } code above.

    // Be wary though, if you try to do this through another type like this:
    // It will not call your setter code, but but the base implementation
    ((IDictionary<string, object>)xDict)["Test2"] = 6;
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you need to create a subclass and can't use a `Dictionary` directly since your "new" indexer doesn't do anything that wouldn't already be done by the `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Anthony, I was just showing the default implementation. Obviously you would want to change the getter and setter methods to handle whatever additional logic you want

Comment: It may not be a bad idea to indicate that more clearly in your code example. Also would be decent to indicate that if you pass an instance of this class to a method expecting a normal dictionary the additional logic added won't get executed due to the mechanics of `new`.

Comment: @Anthony added your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @Anthony I know this looks pointless...but it's to deal with a crappy company code and I cannot fight bad developers and politics...so I need to deserialize a class into a dictionary while one of the keys sometimes ends up as duplicates...by inheriting the dictionary or hashtable class I can avoid duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would just use a dictionary, but there is a language feature for this:

```
class XDict<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return dict[key]; }
        set { dict[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you would need to change the type parameters to match your specific use case; this is merely illustrative of the self-index property.

Any logic for, say, converting values from BSON is left as the proverbial exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
Good old inheritance:

```
class XDict : Hashtable
{
    public override void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        if (key.Equals("something"))
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            base.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're targeting .NET 2.0 or newer you should definitely consider some of the generic options for the added type safety. If anything, it looks like you need something along the lines of a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: Using Hashtable, Vector, etc. is **strongly** discouraged, and has been for over 7 years at least.  They offer you literally nothing over the newer and better generic collections.  If you want un-typed associative collections, use `Dictionary<object, object>` (and also be prepared to suffer through obscure object-equality issues).